# Update Key Value in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework

```
   Profile p = db.Profile.Where(m => m.MemberId == MemberUID).Single();  

   db.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified;      
   p.LastUpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
   db.SaveChanges();
```

I want to update the LastUpdatedDate  but its giving me an error

> "The property 'LastUpdatedDate' is part of the object's key
>   information and cannot be modified."

**NOTE:LastUpdatedDate is not a primary key it is just set as entity key**

I want to update this as it is .. is there any way to do so ? help will be appreciated

**Model**

```
 public partial class Profile 
    {

        public System.DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show the `Model` of where you created the `LastUpdatedDate`? And if you look at the table in SQL, is it a PK?

Comment: It is not a primary Key it is set as Entity key in .edmx file

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138074/whats-entity-key-in-edmx-file

Comment: That is a partial class. Where is the rest? If there is none, why would you create a class that only has a single property of a base type with no security or wrapper?

Comment: @Tipx its just an example I only want to update the entity Key value whisch is set as entitiy key in ,edmx file but not in db

Comment: Don't? Primary keys should be immuable. You can technically do it, but you shouldn't. It's a very strong code-smell (more like a design-smell) to me. Also, your entity in the edmx, or the poco class if using a code-first approach, should be very close to the database entity. You can ignore some attribute, but I'd definitely match the primary key.